# How do I ask if I'm going to be retained as a contractual after I said I'm not interested in a regular post they're offering?

Tags: job-security

I have been a contractual for quite some time now on a client company and for years they have tried to get me as their regular employee but my firm is keen on not letting me go. The client discussed this to me multiple times, and at one point I was asked by my supervisor if they found a way to make my firm let me go, if I even wanted to join them in the first place. I said I wanted to try my luck on other companies. Having said that, I said I still wanted to keep working for them as a contractual while and I still have no concrete plans to leave them in the foreseeable future. I said I wouldn't start looking until the second half of next year.

After some time when this meeting occured, I feel like the supervisor's gone cold on me. I am not included in meetings of upcoming projects, the supervisor doesn't reply sometimes when I use our messenger application, and when we do speak the supervisor's tone is not warm.

Am I reading too much into this? How can I ask of they still have plans to retain me?

Comment: "*I said I wanted to try my luck on other companies*" Yeah.... You say that you still want to keep working for them but *how* did you tell them that? Did you give a timeline? These aren't the kind of conversations you have lightly.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I said I wouldn't start looking until the second half of next year.

Comment: You have said you aren't in their future, so why should they keep you in the loop.  They need to worry about the people who are in  their future.

Answer (score 1):

> I said I wanted to try my luck on other companies.

This isn't something you should ever admit to unless you're absolutely sure that it will be received well. This is something you only say if you've got a manager who has shown that he handles it well when people give notice or indicate that they're looking to move on within X months. Typically such managers make excellent mentors and help employees move on to bigger and better things after a few years, whether internally or externally.

The response your superivsor has had to this news is a clear sign that he's not that type of manager. You're being frozen out of upcoming projects and being treated distantly. These are exceptionally clear signs that **you should start searching for a new job immediately**. It is highly likely that they're looking to replace you and you'll be out of a job within weeks.

Now, it *could* be that thing's aren't quite that bad and they've only decided not to invest in you further or include you in new projects since you've announced that you're leaving. If you'd have no trouble remaining unemployed for a few months if you were suddenly fired or could find a job within your field almost instantly then you can proceed as normal, but you need to recognise the signs here.

Regardless, the fact that they're doing this makes it obvious that they do *not* have plans to retain you long-term. If you wanted to keep working long-term but on an as-needed contractor basis then you should have made that much clearer during that initial conversation. While your post isn't clear whether you're looking to break fully from this company or continue that type of contracting, it's clear that your employer has interpreted it as the former.

Comment: Actually, if they ever decide to not continue with me anymore, I'll fall back to my firm.

Comment: @user19652 Ah hang on, by "*try my luck on other companies*" you mean other clients that your actual employer has? You're not looking to change jobs?

Comment: No, you're right the first time. I actually have a good working relationship with the client, with all the supervisors that handled me commending me on my job performance. When the meeting transpired, I told my current supervisor I wanted to explore newer technologies which I felt wasn't gonna happen where I am at right now. The supervisor then told me to think hard about their offer since it'll be easier to find work on exciting things if I was part of the company. Also, another reason I can't also accept their offer right now is I'm bound by a contract right now with my current firm.